# cv2.imread() always throws a Nonetype only in this one program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu

[image]Here is [my code.](http://pastebin.com/ThiLDdEd)

*Line number 65*

```
ma=cv2.imread(str(files1[x]),1)
```

The result of a `cv2.imread()` is always a `None`.
I have done all basic checks.
The file which i'm trying to read exists.
There are no other variables or functions called `cv2` or `imread`.

I'm using the same version of python in all cases.
I have only one version of `opencv` installed.

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and the folder has read and write permissions for all users.

I have also tested it on Pycharm with a new python file and it works.
I have only problem with this program.
Please let me know if u have any ideas about this problem.

Comment: "I have done all basic checks. The File I'm trying to read does exists." -- I don't see any such tests in the code (which is [far from minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and quite convoluted with all those globals to be honest). `str(files1[x])` -- what's the value of this? Why do you even need the `str` there? There isn't even a test for the situation you're running into, when the image failed to load.

Comment: @DanMašek you are right abt the `str ` it is not required there. But In the image above I have attached u can see the values u were asking for. And in the terminal window I had successfully loaded the same image .

Comment: Interesting. Does it also load it correctly when you do that in the "evaluate code fragment" window in the IDE, rather in the new python interpreter you started in the terminal?

Comment: nope When I try to load in the Ide of this file It does not. But If I create a new python file and then load it works. It doesn't work only in this program.

Comment: New python file in the IDE? With all the same imports? I don't have an easy answer for this one. In your place, I'd start eliminating things from that program until I got the simplest possible variant that still doesn't work. Once you can see what specifically breaks it you can start to investigate why that is so -- right now there's just too much noise.